# TIN when generated goes off the limits ARCGIS 9.3

Tags: arcgis-9.3, tin

i have to creat TINs for a specific areas so the original points or countours are exactly whithin the geographical limits of the area, but when i generate TIN it goes out of those limits and its normal based on the principle of triangulation but is there anyway to gard the same shape and limits after creating a TIN ? right now im using "paint" to clean the mess so please help me :)
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a polygon of your area of interest. When you create the TIN use this polygon as **Clip Polygon**. More information in section "Polygon surface feature types"
 in [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_creating_TIN_surfaces/006000000010000000/).

Comment: thanks for your answer but this doesnt work on TIN i've tried.
but i found the answer on google and i would like to share it with you :

Add the TIN and the polygon layer to ArcMap or ArcScene.
Select 3D Analyst > Create/Modify TIN > Add Features to TIN.
Select the TIN as the Input TIN.
Check the polygon layer.
Use the following settings for the selected layer:

Height source: <None>
Triangluate As: hard clip
Tag value field: <None>